# Is there any way to restrict chart view to only past 200 ( or n ) candles

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am looking to hide the chart that goes beyond the last n candles, the reason for this is that for analysis I don't want to have extra information and wish to create an optimal candle amount for my instrument which has sufficent information, and also I wish to create a n hour fixed range volume profile, this avoids having to hardcode it during backtesting and simply makes the day easier, if I can only view the past 100 candles for example on the 1 minute chart, then I could use visable range volume profile and have the POC for the past 100 minutes without having to draw it by hand every few hours as I back test over weeks.

So far I have tried bg() but it cannot overlay the chart, other questions from 2022 state that this is not possible. I could not find any other way to view the POC for the past N hours without setting it manually and at this point, the problem is beyond my skill level so I would love some help.

1. How can I draw a fixed range volume profile for the past 6 hours via Pinescript
2. How can I only view past n candles for analysis purposes.

Thank you.

Comment: It is still not possible.

Answer (score 0):

max_bars_back,  this is contained in the strategy()
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy

Comment: This function does not restrict visabile range volume profile, nor offer a way to run vpoc over past n hours, nor does it restrict the visual display of candle #'s , it is just to advise a function to run on less bars to save processing power.